# java - Calling Stored Function That Returns a Cursor

Tags: java, sql, plsql, cursor, stored-functions

I have a stored function set up as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PACKAGENAME IS
FUNCTION READ_FUNC(i_name IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
END PACKAGENAME;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PACKAGENAME AS
FUNCTION
READ_FUNC(i_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
    cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    //do stuff
    RETURN cursor;
END READ_FUNC;
```

I'm trying to call it in Java as follows, but I'm getting `not a valid function or procedure name`

```
try(CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("call PACKAGENAME.READ_FUNC(?)")
{
    stmt.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
    // do stuff with result
}
```

It definitely exists because I can `desc PACKAGENAME` and it has my function. I've also been able to call other procedures. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```java
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call PACKAGENAME.READ_FUNC(?) }");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.setString(2, name);
```